# Can an MS Outlook 2016 custom addin add columns to the Select Rooms panel?

Tags: outlook-addin

We are trying to determine the feasibility of adding more columns to the "Select Rooms" panel in Outlook 2016.  We would feed the data in the new custom columns from Active Directory.

Before I dig into learning how to write a add-in we would like to know if it is even possible. Would c# be required?  Or could it be done in Visual Basic with macros?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that - the columns are determined by the particular Address Book provider (MSEMS in your case).